# How can I add more entry to browscap.ini file?

Tags: php, apache, browser, browscap

The official `browscap.ini` files provided there works quite fine, but they can not seem to identify Opera running on Win8 (*identified as 'Default Browser', Opera running on other versions of Windows seems to be identified correctly*), the Epiphany browser (*identified as Chromium*).

How can I add more entry to the file or get a modified, more complete version? Or is my problem a one that can not be solved by `browscap.ini` alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition itself is very simple, you just need to add the browsers in the correct format, that looks like this:

```
[IE 6.0]
browser=IE
Version=6.0
majorver=#6
minorver=#0
frames=True
tables=True
cookies=True
backgroundsounds=True
vbscript=True
javaapplets=True
javascript=True
ActiveXControls=True
Win16=False
beta=False
AK=False
SK=False
AOL=False
Update=False

[Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 98*)]
parent=IE 6.0
platform=Win98
beta=True

[Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT*)]
parent=IE 6.0
platform=WinNT
beta=True

[Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0)]
parent=IE 6.0


[IE 6.0b]
browser=IE
Version=6.0
majorver=#6
minorver=#0
frames=True
tables=True
cookies=True
backgroundsounds=True
vbscript=True
javaapplets=True
javascript=True
ActiveXControls=True
Win16=False
beta=True
AK=False
SK=False
AOL=False
Update=False


[Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0b; Windows 98*)]
parent=IE 6.0
platform=Win98
beta=True

[Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0b; Windows NT*)]
parent=IE 6.0
platform=WinNT
beta=True

[Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0b)]
parent=IE 6.0b
```

The fun part will probably be finding your browscap.ini.  It's location depends on your server.

In a windows server look for it in  *%systemroot%\WINNT\System32\Inetsrv folder.*

In a Linux Server, you might want to put it in */etc/extra/*

Then go to your php.ini file and declare it like this: *browscap = /etc/extra/browscap.ini* 
And finally reboot your server.

If you are using a rented server you might not have access to the file and will need to contact your hosting provider to do any changes.

Finally, once you locate the file (or created it if it doesn't exist)  just edit it with notepad (or text edit if you're a mac user)

Good luck! I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, the fun part for me will be researching the correct info and user agent patterns to add as the entries

Answer (score 1):

I think its better not to rely on browscap.ini because you need to keep it updating and one cannot guarantee that it contains information about all browsers ...

Better use get_browser as mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125) ....

hope it helps you

Comment: otherwise you can edit browscap as mentioned by Ryoku .. but you need exact info about browser for that

Comment: I am not talkin about inbult get_brower() ofcourse it does depends on browscap.ini .. I am talking about getBrowser() that you van see on this page